# Validation message error not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm having a problem with validation message errors for web forms. I need to get an error when both statements are true(both fields are empty). When I change statement **&&** for **||** I'm able to get an error but that's not what I want.Thank you. Here is my C# code

```
protected void CustomValidatorForm_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(drpState.Text) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtRegion.Text))
            args.IsValid = false;
        else
        {
            args.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
```

I'm Trying to run this code for my forms:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpState"  runat="server" CausesValidation="True">
<asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="IL">Illinois</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="IN">Indiana</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="IA">Iowa</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRegion" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server"  />

        </div>
            <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidatorList" runat="server"
                 ControlToValidate ="drpState" OnServerValidate="CustomValidatorForm_ServerValidate"
                 ErrorMessage="At least one of the field need to be filled out" Display="Dynamic"
                 ForeColor="Red"
                >

            </asp:CustomValidator>
            <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidatorForm" runat="server"
                ControlToValidate ="txtRegion" OnServerValidate="CustomValidatorForm_ServerValidate"
                ErrorMessage="At least one of the field need to be filled out" Display="Dynamic"
                ForeColor="Red"

                >

            </asp:CustomValidator>
```

Comment: Test each element individually. Do they each trigger the warning on their own?

Comment: Individually they are working fine!

Comment: Have you defined a "drpState" textbox, I can't see where you do in your code segment?

Comment: Use two different CustomValidatorForm_ServerValidate, one for each control, or one CustomValidator according to your needs. In first case, you can check empty fields using a RequiredFieldValidator

Comment: use required field validator instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I just needed to add this property `ValidateEmptyText="True"` and set it to true. This is how validator should look like:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidatorList" runat="server"
     ControlToValidate ="drpState" OnServerValidate="CustomValidatorForm_ServerValidate"
     ErrorMessage="At least one of the field need to be filled out" Display="Dynamic"
     ForeColor="Red" ValidateEmptyText="True">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using like this ,

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFrom" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtFrom" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" />
```

**Easy way to do this,**

After you create a `<asp:TextBox ID="txtFrom" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>`

type `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator` and press `Tab Button` twice,
You can also give any ErrorMessage as well as define color of the ErrorMessage

Comment: this solution will not work when one of the fields is empty.

Comment: always did worked for me u give it a try .... when u click on the submit button this the * or any ErrorMessage u gave comes